# 1004 Error when copying range from one sheet to another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to copy a range from CopyFrom.xlsx into CopyTo.xlsx using belwo code :

```
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").Clear
Workbooks("CopyFrom.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

However when I place the Clear statement in second place, it gives 1004 error

```
Workbooks("CopyFrom.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").Clear
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5):

Because the `.Clear` exits the cut/copy mode and sets `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. If you try to `.Paste` then there is nothing selected to copy after a `.Clear` which results in the error you got.

Just avoid any code between `.Copy` and `.Paste` to aviod any iterference.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @automaticSoldier don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check icon below the downvote button

Answer (score 4):

If you do it manually, when copying a range and then clearing another range, the copy will get lost.

So Either you clear after or before the copy and paste. Another way could be `Range.Value = Range.Value` it's a one step process so won't matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks, then i think this would be the better approach, for copying.!

Comment: @automaticSoldier that's if you only want to copy values. If you want to copy everything on the cell you could use `Range.Copy DestinationRange` on the same line to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

First Clear the Range:

```
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").Clear
```

Then Copy >> Paste

```
Workbooks("CopyFrom.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Or, you can directly use:

```
Workbooks("CopyTo.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B14").Value = Workbooks("CopyFrom.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"). Value
```

Which is faster in code run-time